# Last update broke program, how to revert?

Tags: updates, update-manager

Yesterday the "software update app" suggested me a list of updates and I decided to apply them. Today I start my computer to find that a program I use every day is not working properly. The program is Lyx. Is there any way to revert this updates? I have tried with Synaptic but it gives me no options to "force version".

In [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uzv5atvoafaeioe/screencast.mp4?dl=0) it can be found a screencast illustrating the problems.

[image]

---

Added image from the screencast:

[image: Screenshot derived from the screencast]

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling it? https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/LyXOnUbuntu#toc3

Comment: @Katu yes, I have tried that with no success.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what "not working properly" means?

Comment: I have recorded a little screencast to illustrate the two problems I am having. It can be found in [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uzv5atvoafaeioe/screencast.mp4?dl=0).

Comment: I took the liberty to add an image from the screencast. Please remove if you feel it isn't needed or helpful.

Comment: It's also possible that the ppa somehow doesn't play nice with your system following the updates. Could you use `ppa-purge` to return to the version supplied by 18.04?

Comment: I have tried to run "sudo apt-get install lyx=2.3.0-1" but it says that version does not exist. Also other combinations such as "sudo apt-get install lyx=2.3.0" and "sudo apt-get install lyx=2.3.0-1~bionic~ppa1" with same results. I need Lyx urgently working again, how can I return to my previous version? What should be the command to use ppa-purge?

Comment: Check your /var/cache/apt/archives for the older deb. It's probably not there (or apt would have installed it), so visit packages.ubuntu.com or launchpad.net for the older package. Apt will install a /path/to/package.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to re install version 2.3.0-1 (lyx - 2.3.0-1~artful~ppa1 in [this link](https://launchpad.net/~lyx-devel/+archive/ubuntu/release/+packages)). For that, I manually downloaded the packages [fonts-lyx_2.3.0-1~artful~ppa1_all.deb](https://launchpad.net/~lyx-devel/+archive/ubuntu/release/+files/fonts-lyx_2.3.0-1~artful~ppa1_all.deb), [lyx-common_2.3.0-1~artful~ppa1_all.deb](https://launchpad.net/~lyx-devel/+archive/ubuntu/release/+files/lyx-common_2.3.0-1~artful~ppa1_all.deb) and [lyx_2.3.0-1~artful~ppa1_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/~lyx-devel/+archive/ubuntu/release/+files/lyx_2.3.0-1~artful~ppa1_amd64.deb) from [here](https://launchpad.net/~lyx-devel/+archive/ubuntu/release/+sourcepub/8863078/+listing-archive-extra) (which indeed is part of [this](https://launchpad.net/~lyx-devel/+archive/ubuntu/release/+packages)). Then I removed the 3 corresponding packages from my computer (manually using Synaptic) and finally I installed the downloaded packages using "right click --> software manager". Now I have Lyx 2.3.0-1 in Xubuntu 18.04 happily running, and will not update for a long time.